# Pointer syntax *object vs object

Tags: objective-c

What is the difference between:

```
NewClass *object = [NewClass new];
printf("%s", [object stringValue]);
```

and

```
NewClass *object = [NewClass new];
printf("%s", [*object stringValue]);
```

The second one of course doesn't work. But why? When exactly do you use the `*` and not?

Comment: the short answer is `objc_msgSend` expects an object pointer.

Comment: For the love of god, don't dereference an Objective-C object like this.  It used to work under the old 32 and 64-bit runtimes, but isa's just a bit-soup at this point.

Comment: also use `NSLog(@"%@", object)` for printing objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer is misleading, so even if it's a duplicate question, I'll just provide an explanation here.

First, it's not true that you only use `*object` for declaring and never for using. Pointers in Objective-C are just pointers, so you use them accordingly.

As an example, here's a typical pattern in Cocoa where you pass (the pointer to) an `NSError` instance by reference:

```
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = [self methodThatMayFailWithError:&error];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    //handle error
}
```

where `-methodThatMayFailWithError:` is declared as

```
- (BOOL)methodThatMayFailWithError:(NSError **)error {
    if (somethingVeryBadHappened) {
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"myAppDomain" code:42 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : @"You screwed up!"}];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

As you can see the implementation dereferenced the `NSError **` pointer to get a `NSError *`.

So pointers are pointers. Period.

That said, in Objective-C pointers are used pretty seamlessly. This is because the Objective-C  runtime is built for manipulating pointers to objects. Consider this example:

```
NSString *aString = @"Hello";
NSUInteger stringLength = [aString length];
```

`[aString length]` will - more or less - result in the following runtime code

```
objc_msgSend(aString, @selector(length));
```

Now if you take a look at the signature of `objc_msgSend`

```
id objc_msgSend(id theReceiver, SEL theSelector, ...)
```

you'll notice that it takes a parameter of type `id`, which means a pointer to an object.

The example illustrates how the whole Objective-C message passing system is designed to use pointers and that's why you declare pointers and you don't dereference them before using them.

This also causes a sort of misuse of the term `object`.

```
NSString *aString;
```

We typically say that `aString` is a `NSString`, whereas it's actually a pointer to `NSString`. This may seem confusing, but the design of the languages makes it pretty transparent, so it has become part of the common terminology.